# ipad 2 - How to use 2048x1536 resolution

Tags: ipad, drawing, 2d, max, screen-resolution

I'm writing a 2d application for ipad2. I would like to use 2048*1536 pixel coordinate system instead of 1024x768. It is possible?
For example I would like to draw a rectangle like the following

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(2000,1000,10,10);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
```

and see the rectanle on the screen. With ipad(one) this is not possible.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that's possible even on the newest retina iPad. Since it still uses the 1024x768 coordinate system and pixel doubling.

Why do you want to use 2048x1536 as the co-ordinate system, couldn't you just divide those by 2 and achieve the same effect?

Comment: I already divided by 2 the dimension and the position of the 2d objects. Diving by 2 i get the problem since I obtain object with width equals to 7.5 point on  a grid with size 4.  In other words position and dimensions of each 2d object has to be multiple of grid size. To solve the problem i can multiply by 2 all object dimension and grid size. But doing this with 1024x768 resolution I cannot show all the content that I need to present to the user.